# Accessing a Microsoft Access table from a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Instead of Accessing MySQL from Microsoft Access using ODBC is it possible to do it the other way around ? By that i mean: Accessing a Microsoft Access table from a MySQL database.

Comment: You might be able to find a way to do it, if you look enough and are willing to endure needless complexity, but it's a very bad idea. Rather think along the lines of accessing both databases from a third program, and manipulating/merging the data there.

Comment: Do you know why i can access a MySQL database in Microsoft Access (via the ODBC connecter), but not the other way around ? Or is it possible ?

Comment: You can do that because Microsoft Access is more than just a database. It has a user interface and a programming environment, so it can act as an application "front end", whereas mySQL is purely a "back end" relational database management system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all reasonable intents and purposes, no it's not possible to access a Microsoft Access table from a MySQL database.

This is because MySQL is purely a [**RDBMS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) (**R**elational **D**ata**B**ase **M**anagement **S**ystem), whereas Microsoft Access is more of a [Swiss Army Knife](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SwissArmyKnife) because you can use it to create an entire small-scale application from user interface through business logic to database.

In other words, Microsoft Access fills the role of an application ["front end"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends) as well as "back end", whereas MySQL is only back end. Generally you'd need the functionality of a front end to connect to a back end, whereas a back end expects to be accessed from a front end thus isn't particularly well equipped to do other than listen and respond.

Comment: Good explanation of "front end" vs. "back end", but there is at least one example of a "back end" database that allows such external connections: Microsoft SQL Server. Its "[Linked Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ff772782.aspx)" feature enables us to establish connections to other databases, so it is possible for SQL Server to "link to" an Access database (details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26829350/2144390)) or some other database that offers OLEDB/ODBC connections.

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you. Yes, there's also DB2 federation, and similar things in other DBMSs - it's just that using a database in such a manner is not usually the normal or preferred way of doing such things. That's why we have ETL tools and programming languages. My answer is geared for the audience :)

Comment: I quite agree. Just because we *can* do something doesn't necessarily mean that we *should*. :)